# Cannot load jquery in angular controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have an SPA in angular.
I want to insert a QR code, using a jquery plugin.

All my controllers and my javascript are in my `index.html`. When user visits `screen.html` or `keybord.html` , there is another small page inside those pages

the controller of `qr.html`   has

```
jQuery('#cardQR').qrcode({
        text :"yo"
});
```

When I first go to `screen.html` the QR is there, if I go to `keybord.html` or go back to `screen.html` the QR renders for half a second and gets lost.

I guess the QR jquery plugin gets loaded once in `index.html` and never again because index does not reloads again, only screen or keybord. I may be wrong.

I dont know how to fix this.  Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery in Angular controllers is usually really bad practice, I would advise you to use something like [angular-qrcode](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode) for a more 'Angular way' implementation.

As for your question, this isn't possible to answer without seeing more of your code, could you create a fiddle/plunkr ?